# Maximum value of an mllib Vector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've created an ML pipeline with Apache Spark using mllib.
The evaluator result is a DataFrame with a column "probability", which is a mllib vector of probabilities (similar to predict_proba in scikit-learn).

```
val rfPredictions = rfModels.bestModel.transform(testing)
val precision = evaluator.evaluate(rfPredictions)
```

I tried something like this with no success:

```
rfPredictions.select("probability").map{c => c.getAs[Vector](1).max}
<console>:166: error: value max is not a member of 
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

I want a new column with the max of this probabilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vector* doesn't have a `max` method. Try `toArray.max`:

```
rfPredictions.select("probability").map{ c => c.getAs[Vector](1).toArray.max }
```

or `argmax`:

```
rfPredictions.select("probability").map{ c => {
    val v = c.getAs[Vector](1)
    v(v.argmax)
}}
```

---

To add the max as a new column, define a udf and use it with `withColumn` function:

```
val max_proba_udf = udf((v: Vector) => v.toArray.max)

rfPredictions.withColumn("max_prob", max_proba_udf($"probability"))
```

Comment: Yes, I think that works. I'm getting an RDD[Double] as a result, so I cannot add that as a column in my DataFrame. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spark > 2.0

With **ml, not mllib** this will work next way:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector

just_another_df.select("probability").map{ c => c.getAs[DenseVector](0).toArray.max }
```

Using udf

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector

val max_proba_udf = udf((v: DenseVector) => v.toArray.max)

val rfPredictions = just_another_df.withColumn("MAX_PROB", max_proba_udf($"probability"))
```